# Unrecognized Keyword and Statement Type (FROM)

Tags: mysql

I am deleting records from my database when a button is pressed that deletes the artist and all associating albums. I have a button solely dedicated to deleting a single album which works fine and deletes the album.
When pressing the button it comes up with an error in Java, so I tried it on phpmyadmin and got the same error:

2 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected keyword. (near "FROM" at position 32)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "FROM" at position 32)

I am using XAMPP v3.2.2

SQL query that works deleting album:

```
"DELETE FROM album WHERE album.albumID = '"+ albumID+ "';";
```

Query that doesnt work and produces the error in both Java and phpmyadmin:

```
"DELETE FROM collection,artist FROM collection LEFT JOIN artistAlbum ON collection.albumID = artistAlbum.albumID LEFT JOIN artist on artist.artistID = artistAlbum.artistID WHERE artist.artistID = '"+artistID+"' AND collection.userID ='"+databaseTest.userLoggedIn()+"';";
```

I make sure to print out values and have used the actual values when doing it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection. Never concatenate strings like that. Use parameterized queries instead

Comment: You have an extra `FROM` in the failing query, plus you seem to be trying to delete from a join.  What effect are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @JohnBollinger You can delete from a join, you just need to be careful that you know exactly what's being deleted.

Comment: Thankyou, for some reason I overlooked that

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I guess you can with MySQL, but (1) not all SQL implementations allow the same, and (2) it's not clear whether that's really what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, sorry if I didnt make myself clear. I wanted to remove all albums that are associated with a single artist. The collection table is where the album IDs are stored and artistAlbum is a link between the artistID and albumID.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have two `FROM` clauses. If you're deleting with a join, you list the tables that you're deleting from *before* the `FROM` keyword.

```
"DELETE collection,artist 
FROM collection 
LEFT JOIN artistAlbum ON collection.albumID = artistAlbum.albumID 
LEFT JOIN artist on artist.artistID = artistAlbum.artistID 
WHERE artist.artistID = '"+artistID+"' AND collection.userID ='"+databaseTest.userLoggedIn()+"';";
```

Comment: Thankyou, for some reason I overlooked the two FROM clauses when trying to overcome a different erro. Thanks!